# How to send browser push notifications when the tab or browser is closed in django?

Tags: django, push-notification

I want to implement push notifications in my project with django.

I want to show the notifications even when the browser and the tab are closed, I have seen that this is implemented by Facebook or web telegram.

Anyone have any idea how to do it?
Thank you all

Comment: What kind of notifications? desktop notifications, email or browser notification...

Comment: I want something similar to this: https://content-static.upwork.com/blog/uploads/sites/3/2017/11/29185051/mac-desktop-notification-examples-e1512010275977.png

Comment: That's a mac notification. From what I know creating system based notifications is not trivial, you are best off implementing an email notification imo. If you do want to do that, then go ahead and do some research on it.